# MongoDB Compass connection refused from remote

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm attempting to connect to a MongoDB database via Compass to make sure entries are actually going in as I want them to to the database, and the app hosted on the server alongside the database is connecting just fine with a local connection, however I am continuously getting ECONNREFUSED errors when trying to connect via compass. I have updated my bind settings to read as follows, and have tried all of the methods I've found on other questions, as well as firewall stuff.

Bind:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, localhost, api.pixelshift.xyz, 0.0.0.0
```

Connection URI Being Used:

```
mongodb://dislife:password@api.pixelshift.xyz:27017/dislife
```

Comment: What happens if you use URI connection string `mongodb://dislife:password@api.pixelshift.xyz:27017/`?

Comment: That would mean that compass is doing a DNS lookup on "api.pixelshift.xyz" and getting some IP address, and then attempting to connect to that IP at a port 27017.  The operating system running on whatever machine has that IP doesn't see anything listening on port 27017, so it replies "connection refused".  Do you know what IP address is being returned by DNS for that host? Can you confirm that IP is actually assigned to your server?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that IP is actually assigned to my server, and I do not have any other IPs/domains pointed at it that would be conflicting either.